# AngularJs Resolve Response of a Promise (UI.Router + $http.get)

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

apothekenService.getApotheke returns a promise. response.data within the promise is a json object which is delivered correctly, I can see that in the first console.log.

How can I get this json object to my variable in the resolve? When I do the same in a controller I just use $scope and bind the variable within the response but in this case I don't have a scope.

```
angular.module("test", ["ngAnimate", "ngCookies", "ngTouch", "ngSanitize", "ngResource", "ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.showErrors", "myApothekenService"]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $uiViewScrollProvider, showErrorsConfigProvider) {
  $uiViewScrollProvider.useAnchorScroll;
  return $stateProvider.state("root", {
    abstract: true,
    controller: "RootCtrl",
    resolve: {
      Apotheke: function(apothekenService) {
        this.apo = {};
        apothekenService.getApotheke().then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          return this.apo = response.data;
        });
        console.log(this.apo);
        return this.apo;
      }
    }
  });
}).controller("RootCtrl", function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, Apotheke) {
  $scope.apotheke = Apotheke;
  console.log($scope.apotheke);
});
```

Comment: I usually return $promises from my Services and I resolve them in Controllers

Answer (score 1):

You know **this** inside the promise resolve function (then) is different than the **this** inside the parent resolve function. If you want to use this pattern, the usual convention is to capture **this** in a local variable **self**, and use that throughout your resolve function.

But anyways, I will just do as below. This way, the controller code won't execute until the resolve promise is resolved.

```
  Apotheke: function(apothekenService) {
    return apothekenService.getApotheke();
  }**
```

Comment: The real problem was another one. RootCtrl is not loaded. So the solution for me was to load the variable in the service and then load the variable from the service in each subcontroller.